# form action with ie

Tags: php

```
<?php

if($_REQUEST['add'])
{

 echo $_REQUEST['add'];

}
?>

<form action="test.php">

<input type="image" src="other/images/buttons/addposting.gif" name="add" value="add123" id="add" />

</form>
```

i have written this code ,i m getting $_request['add'] as add123 in firefox and chrome but in ie i m not getting its value whats the proble ,the code is as below

Answer (score 2):

Check that the array actually has the 'add' key.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['add'])) {
    echo $_REQUEST['add'];
}
```

If you want to make sure all browsers are receiving the same data, dump the contents of the request array:

```
var_dump($_REQUEST['add']);
```

This will output the actual data received by the POST or GET.

Answer (score 2):

What you get from IE is $_REQUEST['add.x'] and $_REQUEST['add.y'];
The **IE does NOT support the value attribute on input image elements**.
IE will only send you the coordinates the user clicked in the image, which is the way a input image element is supposed to behave.

Comment: IIRC, the spec is a bit fuzzy on the subject of values for image inputs. I think a strict reading says that it should be sent, but I don't have time to check right now. Either way, the practical part of the answer is that IE doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code sample, but my guess is you have a problem with your html, not with your PHP. You could check the html with the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/).